# Time delay counter in 8086

Tags: x86, emulation, x86-16

I have the following code that delays the printing of a message specified by a user. But, having problems in understanding it. For eg: In line 23, why it is written MOV AX,BX, i can't see BX containeing any value then what is moved in AX register? Also, why do we write  MOV CL,0AH. Please help!

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA

MSGIN DB 'Enter delay duration (0-50): $'
MSG1 DB 'This is Microprocessor!$'
 DELAYTIME DW 0000H

.CODE

MOV DX,@DATA
MOV DS,DX
LEA DX,MSGIN
MOV AH,09H
INT 21H

IN1:    
    MOV AH,01H
    INT 21H
    CMP AL,0DH   ;
    JE NXT
    SUB AL,30H
    MOV DL,AL
    MOV AX,BX
    MOV CL,0AH
    MUL CL
    MOV BX,AX
    AND DX,00FFH
    ADD BX,DX
    MOV DELAYTIME,BX
    LOOP IN1


 NXT:        MOV CX,DELAYTIME
        MOV DL,10
        MOV AH,02H
        INT 21H

LEA SI,MSG1

LP:    PUSH DX
    MOV DL,[SI]
    CMP DL,'$'
    JE NXT2
   MOV AH,02H
 INT 21H
 ADD SI,1
 POP DX
 MOV DI,DELAYTIME
 MOV AH, 0
 INT 1Ah
 MOV BX, DX  

 Delay:
 MOV AH, 0
 INT 1Ah
 SUB DX, BX
 CMP DI, DX
 JA Delay

 LOOP LP

    NXT2:   MOV AH,4CH 
             INT 21H


 END
```

Comment: _"why do we write `MOV CL,0AH`?"_ To move the value `0AH` (==`10`) into register `CL`.

Answer (score 0):

The loop starting at IN1 reads a series of characters terminated by a carriage return. The characters are assumed to be decimal digits and are converted to a binary number in BX.

BX is assumed to be zero when the program is entered.